# Why MeaditR couldn't find my assembly inside AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatr

I use MediatR in .net5 and my handler is in the application project which I referenced to my API project (My API use the Application layer).

**My first question** is simple:
why MediatR could find my reference with the below line in StartUp

```
        services.AddControllers();
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Consultant.Application");
        services.AddMediatR(assembly);
```

But it doesn't work with bellow line:

```
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

and it returns this error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException",
> "Message": "Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Consultant.Application.Consultant.Commands.CreateConsultant.CreateConsultCommand,Consultant.Application.Consultant.Commands.CreateConsultant.CreateConsultDto].
> Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
> for examples.",

I even got all of my assemblies via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and I see my `Consultant.Application` inside its object but why MediatR could not find it?

[image]

this is my project structure:
[image]

**My second question** is: getting all assembly with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and use it for example in AddMediatR or AddAutoMapper or whatever doesn't have a negative effect on performance? I mean, isn't it better to use specific assembly forexample (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Consultant.Application")) instead of all assembly in the application?

Comment: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection , https://medium.com/swlh/dependency-injection-v-mediatr-a-simple-c-benchmark-32630ff864ea could help,

Comment: @alessandro Thanks for your comment. I read it and it was nice but frankly, It's not my answer. I am just wondering why MediatR cant find my Application layer inside my assembly although it exists!

Comment: GetAssemblies will gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain, your dependant assembly is loaded on first use, and doesn't appear in the list of assemblies in the current AppDomain at the warm up. why don't you use services.AddMediatR(typeof(MyHandlerInDependantAssembly)) ?

Comment: @alessandro I don't know why! An interesting point is that It worked correctly before! suddenly It didn't work and I had to change it with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Consultant.Application")!